# Run MSIEXEC as an admin

Tags: powershell

I've got an issue with an automated software deployment & am looking for a little insight. I'm trying to run an MSI as an admin, I've created `$scriptadmincreds` (PS credentials) that work great. I know that these creds work because I can see that msiinstaller is using them to run in the event viewer (they also work to create PS drives, etc)

Here's my code that does not work:

```
$Arguments = "/package C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\anyconnect-win-4.5.05030-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi /norestart /passive /lv c:\users\testuser\desktop\msilogs\install.log"

Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec.exe' -WorkingDirectory 'C:\Windows\System32' -ArgumentList $Arguments -Credential $ScriptAdminCreds
```

If I simply omit the `-Credential` parameter it runs fine. However it prompts me for admin credentials (if provided via GUI it works great!).

But this script will be run unattended. I just wish I could figure out why running this as an admin is failing (it doesnt even output an MSI log and event viewer just says it started... then stopped with no error or message.

I've tried researching and some people say to start your argument list with a `/c` -- I've tried that to no avail.

Comment: If you are asking if you can elevate to administrator automatically without provoking the UAC prompt, the answer is no. (UAC is designed specifically to prevent this.) If that's not your question, please clarify.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to find a way to run an MSI installer (using powershell) when non-admins logon. Non-admins wont have the creds needed if they're prompted by UAC.
I guess I could have the script disable UAC, install the MSI, then re-enable UAC?

Comment: You cannot disable UAC automatically (silently) as a non-admin, because doing so requires elevation. You cannot run a command elevated if you are not elevated without provoking the UAC prompt. This is by design. (If this were possible, it's exactly what all malware would do!) You will need to abandon this approach altogether, because you cannot elevate automatically without provoking the UAC prompt, and you definitely should not disable UAC.

Comment: I would disagree on the "don't disable UAC" part, as long as you use a dedicated admin account for administrative tasks (and only for those) and a restricted user account for everything else. YMMV.

Comment: In the case where you use a restricted account for everything else you have to authenticate to perform admin tasks anyway, so IMO there's not an advantage (and some potential risk) to disabling UAC in that use case. So I guess we'd have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: I wouldn't have an issue with disabling the UAC prompts just for the purpose of installing an AnyConnect Client -- then immediately re-enabling it. I just can't think of any other way to make this happen with powershell.

Comment: You can't disable and re-enable UAC without rebooting, and you'd need to be elevated anyway, so that's not going to work. You need to use a different approach altogether that doesn't involve trying to work around security. Software distribution systems use an elevated service account - you will need to do something like that.